# enable https on Dell Networking N1548P

Tags: switch, security, dell

I am trying to enable https and disable http to make dell more secure. I am trying to generate self-sign certificate with these commands and having this error.

```
(config)#crypto certificate 1 generate

(config-crypto-cert)#exit

Certificate generation failed. Please check logs for more details..

#show logging

SSLT[emWeb]: sslt_api.c(1201) 607965 %% SSLT: ssltCertificateGenerate keyFile not exist
```

Answer (score 2):

The log message points in the right direction - you first need to generate key pairs on the switch:

```
console(config)#crypto key generate dsa
console(config)#crypto key generate rsa
console(config)#ip ssh server
console(config)#crypto certificate 1 generate
console(config-crypto-cert)#key-generate
console(config-crypto-cert)#exit
console(config)#ip http secure-server
```

https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/de-de/000121381/how-to-set-up-management-access-for-the-n1500-series-switch?lang=en

Comment: Console help says key generate - Regenerate SSL RSA key. I did not try as it does not look rational. I already ran crypto key generate rsa command

Comment: console(config-crypto-cert)#key-generate console(config-crypto-cert)#organization-name BIGORG should be run otherwise it gives an error.